# Unable to add content?

Tags: 7, users, nodes

I am working on a project with a fresh install of Drupal 7.41 and the customer wanted to use a Themeforest layout.

Installation of core, theme and modules went without a problem, however, when I try to create content via 'article or basic page' nothing happens except a page refresh. No content shows in the content list and no content is created.

Yet, I am able to create a webform with the webform module.

#### Notes

- I have checked my logs and there are no errors.  None!
- I cleared my cache several times
- I am running as Admin and the proper permissions have been checked.
- My roles are in the proper order.  (Admin being at the bottom)
- I created a new custom content type and that does not work either.  Even after enabling permissions.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated as I have never encountered this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is an issue with the CKEditor module.  Once I disabled it I am now able to post content as normal.  I will have to find another WYSIWYG to replace it.

Comment: Have you checked that the ckeditor javascript library is correctly installed in your sites/all/libraries folder? Is it the correct version of the library? Visit admin/config/content/ckeditor . If there are any problems with th elibrary it will show there.